# CSS with Happstack

Tags: haskell, happstack

I'm wondering what the best way to go about including css in Happstack webpages would be. I tried google, with no luck, so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: Did you see [this example](http://hpaste.org/47216)? I've never used Happstack, but it definitely looks like they link in a CSS file on line 15.

Comment: @JeffreyBurka I saw it, but it doesn't show how they get happstack to serve up the css file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method for me was to serve them from a static folder. Eg adding a handler like:

```
dir "static" $ serveDirectory DisableBrowsing [] "www"
```

Replace `"www"` with the directory that you want happstack to use. For more information on serveDirectory, [see the Haddock documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/happstack-server/6.1.3/doc/html/Happstack-Server-FileServe.html#g:1).

Then I have a `www/css` folder where all of my css lives. I use Blaze templates so I link to them all directly:

```
H.link ! A.rel "stylesheet" ! A.type_ "text/css" ! A.href "/static/css/foo.css"
```